# Large document is sluggish and its pictures not visible in Web Layout

Tags: microsoft-word

I recently upgraded Office from 2010 to 2013. I have a large (700 pages) and complex document that contains text and pictures (inserted as In-Line With Text). The document has two problems:

1) Pictures are no longer visible in Word 2013. I noticed that if I change the view from Web Layout (which is the most suitable view for this particular document) to Print Layout, then the pictures become visible. The following workarounds did not help:
- Changing the position/wrapping of the pictures (which are clickable elements, if all white) 
- using the "convert to latest document format"option (the document is right now in 2013 docx format)

2) In addition, Word reacts very slowly when I edit this document; all actions are very sluggish, with a delay of about 2 seconds, which is frustrating. The following are causes that I've ruled out, or workarounds that don't help for this problem:

- PC performance: same problems affect this doc when opened on other PCs, with other Windows and Word versions
- deleting contents from it till the document remains very small doesn't help
- copy and paste everything into a new document doesn't help
- save as another document (still docx format, or word 2003 DOC format; maitaining compatibility or not) doesn't help

The only workarounds that help (speed of operation becomes normal) are:
- deleting most of the contents of the document reduces the sluggishness
- viewing the document in Print Layout *somewhat* reduces the sluggishness

Any suggestions what I can try to get rid of these 2 problems - which seem to be related - for my document?

Comment: Have you tried Openoffice/Libreoffice?

Comment: Yes but I would like to keep using this document with Word 2013 in this case

Comment: Just for interest then, was it more responsive?

Comment: I haven't opened this particular document in OO after it became corrupted, and no longer have OO installed

Comment: Just to complete the point: as this document still has this problem, I had another go today at trying smth new to fix it. Having installed Libre Office and opened it there, the performance is no better than in Word, in fact LO even crashes after this document has been opened for a while. Seems like what I need is to somehow "de-corrupt" this document, as I have tried absolutely everything I could think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had this problem with a large document - Word 2013 was sluggish and not displaying pictures in web layout.  The document was about 8 MB and 900 pages.

After some investigation I concluded this is a deficiency in Word's rendering of web layout.

For the record:

1. Various of ways of 'tidying up' the document had no effect (saving to rtf format and opening the rtf file; opening and saving in LibreOffice as docx and opening the docx file; repeating but using odt format; copying without the final pargraph mark; etc)
2. LibreOffice, although sluggish, was able to render the document in web layout
3. Using the old doc format allowed Word to render OK
4. Images display correctly near the start of the document
5. Splitting the document into subdocuments and a master shows the same problem

The clincher for me was discovering that the same picture inserted at successive locations rendered squashed up and then not at all. Here's a screenshot from the place in the document where things go wrong.

[image]

So there is a point in the document beyond which images do not render, as though a limit has been reached and an attempt is made to render the image by squashing it vertically.  The limit varies with the pane size for displaying the document e.g. if the navigation pane is displayed the limit on image displaying is moved up the document.

This is a bug in Word's image rendering in Web Layout of the later file format.

In my case, since I wanted to use Word rather than switch to LibreOffice, and use docx rather than doc format, I split the document into several separate smaller documents; these display images OK although are a little inconvenient.

Comment: Many thanks for your input, this does seem to be the same bug. And splitting is the (very suboptimal) workaround that I went with in the end also!

Answer (score 7):

The long thread
[Word 2013: Extremely slow saving and pasting plain text in long documents](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-2013-extremely-slow-saving-and-pasting-plain/94718ebd-0a1a-4542-904a-33185a115ae2?page=1),
from January 2013, contains some workarounds that worked for some people.

Here is the list. I suggest to try them one-by-one and undo the ones that do not help:

1. Save As in "Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)" format
2. Save the document in RTF file format, open a new Word 2013 document and import the RTF file, then save in Word 2013 format
3. Disable hardware acceleration in  "Advanced settings"
4. Disable "Allow Background saves" (some people report that enabling Always create a backup on save also helps)
5. Turn off [Background Repagination](http://word.tips.net/T001261_Turning_Off_Background_Repagination.html)
6. [Reduce the size of included pictures](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reduce-the-file-size-of-a-picture-8db7211c-d958-457c-babd-194109eb9535)
7. Break apart the document and only rejoin the pieces when printing.
   See these references for master-subdocuments in Word :

   1. [Understanding Master and Subdocuments](http://word.tips.net/T000221_Understanding_Master_and_Subdocuments.html)
   2. [Creating a Master Document Using Existing Subdocuments](http://word.tips.net/T001739_Creating_a_Master_Document_Using_Existing_Subdocuments.html)
8. Check add-ins in File / Options / Add-ins / Manage / COM Add-ins,
   and disable the ones you don't use. You can launch Winword with the parameter `/safe`
   to work without any add-in.
9. Change the default printer to a virtual PDF printer
10. Copy-paste the document to a new Word 2013 document
11. Disable "Spelling and Grammar Check"
12. Upgrade to Office 2016
13. Get a faster computer with more memory

The article
[10 Microsoft Word 2013 headaches and how to cure them](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2027605/10-microsoft-word-2013-headaches-and-how-to-cure-them.html)
might also be useful.

Comment: The 10 tips were just for your information. I think that my list above is quite exhaustive, so as far as I can see, your options are : 1) Go back to 2010 (to be honest, I don't see a big difference in functionality between it and 2013, whatever Microsoft says), or (2) Upgrade to 2016 in the hope that the bug is really fixed as reported, or (3) Wait of course for a better answer (which you should do in any case, at least for the duration of the bounty), or (4) Try a free alternative to Office such as LibreOffice. These are all the ideas I can think of.

Comment: Just as an update: Office 2016 renders this document in the same sluggish way, and copying/pasting into a new Word 2016/2013/2010 document does not help, even when done chapter by chapter. Same for Word 2010. Opening it in LibreOffice does not either. I do need to keep extending this document and I am at my wit's end as to how I can get it to be more responsive, other than the workaround I observed of keeping it in Print (rather than Web) view, which given the layout of this document, is severely suboptimal

Comment: I have added more advice : points 5-9 & 13 above. There are also other free alternatives to Word which have a good reputation : [Kingsoft](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/kingsoft-office-freeware.html) and [SoftMaker](http://www.freeoffice.com/en/) (but which I never tried personally). See also [these tips](http://www.howtogeek.com/74007/how-to-speed-up-microsoft-word-2007-and-2010/).

Comment: you are amazing, thanks so much :) i'm afraid i've already tried all of these, except for 6. which I can't do much about as the doc does contain lots of information including pictures.

Comment: I'll just remind you, though, that the doc broke down suddenly at some point rather than gradually (as would have been the case if bloating was the cause), so really the solution must be trying to repair the document. The only way to do that that I can think of is to, as you suggest, break down the document in several smaller docs. In my case that would make work a lot more cumbersome, but still I've tried a version of that, (combinatorically there are many ways to partition a document...) with not much success

Comment: If the problem is due to something in the document, breaking it up might help to pinpoint it. I have sometimes "fixed" bad documents by storing them in a very limited format, for example RTF, then back to DOC (if you don't need advanced features or can recreate them later).

Comment: re-saving through RTF did not help in this case. The doc has many chapters so dividing it in any meaningful way and saving it as multiple documents would be very cumbersome

Comment: Perhaps not cumbersome at all - see my additions to point 7.

Comment: ok so I've tried smth else - a binary search. I deleted the first half of the doc then saved the remainder as a separate doc; then vice-versa (deleted 2nd half, saved 1st half as separate doc). And so-on and so -forth, I progressively halved each such new document hoping to arrive at a completely sluggish "trimmed" document that would identify what the "problematic content" of the initial document was - but there was no such thing. Equally, there was no "trimmed" document that suddenly became sluggishness-free after a certain trimming step.

Comment: Just to add that all other docs on my PC are normally responsive and not sluggish at all, so it's not a problem with the PC (which is new&powerful) or with Word (2016), but definitely with this particular doc, although from what you can see it's impossible to identify the exact part of it that became corrupt

Comment: had a look at the master-subdocuments links. I still think it would be more cumbersome than keeping this document as a single entitiy - but it might be that I'll never be able to fix its sluggishness problem, in which case I'll have no choice but to resort to this workaround. If you have the energy for a final go at this, please see my 2 posts above about my binary search attempt.

Comment: Questions: (1) Is a new document is also slow. (2) Did you try point 9 above, (3) How large is the document on the disk, and how large are the parts. (4) Are all the parts equally sluggish, (5) Try to pass through a non-Microsoft format such as ODT, (6) How much RAM do you have.

Comment: 1) no; new documents, as well as all other of my documents (which are much smaller than the one in question) are just fine in terms of how responsive Word is when scrolling and editing; 2) yes, I set it to StatnovaPDFPrinter, then restarted Word - same..; 3) 30MB; not sure which parts you mean; if you mean when I did the binary search thing, I think the size in MB was proportional to how much content (and pictures) were in that subdocument;

Comment: 4) as I said, subdocuments only stopped being sluggish when they were so small (maybe <100 pages) that it's have been impractical to keep; I didn't identify any subdocument that was sluggish disproportionately to its size if that makes sense; 5) SaveAs .odt -> equally sluggish; 6) 4GB. Really appreciate your help! Let me know if you think it would make sense if I just sent you the document to have a look

Comment: If you make it available for download, I will have a look at it.

Comment: tried to PM you (unsusccessfuly) as I'd rather not post the download link publicly; let me know how I can send it to you

Comment: But can I PM you the encryption key or in some other way not make the document accessible publicly?

Comment: I have tried both Word 2010 & 2016 and I have no problems with the document - it's not sluggish at all and requires only 150MB of RAM. I could maybe suggest disabling spellcheck, since you have so many errors that Word complained. Also, viewing in Print layout seems faster than in Web layout (after some dozens of seconds for formatting). Questions: (1) Have you tried launching `WINWORD.EXE /safe` ? (2) Which operations in particular are sluggish ? (3) Are you using the English version of Office?

Comment: very surprised to hear this. The doc was sluggish not just on my old pc but also on my new one, which is very powerful; that's in addition to Word versions being different as well (2013 and 2016 respectively). Instant spellcheck I had already disabled. (1) yes, it was among your initial sggestions and I had tried it, with no results; (2) when writing, the letters appear after 1-2 seconds, then to move the cursor with (ctrl+)arrows is sluggish, scrolling is ok; (3) yes

Comment: Very weird - this then has something to do with your environment, but why only for this one document? Do you have any other document exceeding 800 pages? I suppose you have also disabled Grammar checking. Try to boot in Safe mode to see if the slow-down is caused by some installed product.

Comment: I don't have any other document that comes close to that size. Grammar I keep disabled as well, true. I booted in Safe mode, but Word 2016 says it cannot run when Windows is in safe mode (?!). I'll try this on my old PC soon as well. I'd be very surprised if this was environment-specific, since as I mentioned these are 2 different PCs, both fast, with different Word and Windows versions, yet they show the same sluggishness with this (and no other) doc

Comment: Weird, weird,weird. I have managed to duplicate your problem by creating a 1200-page document which became too slow to work with, so I'm now convinced  that the problem does exist and is probably related to some inefficiency in Word. I have no idea why this is only happening to you and not to me, as all my ideas were listed above. Suggestions: (1) Try the document on other computers to see. (2) Control Panel / Programs & features, right-click Microsoft Office, Change and then Repair. (3) Use another editor for some time such as Libreoffice.

Comment: Will try on other PCs, as I find them :) Office installation was 1-hour old on my new laptop when I first observed that problem exists here as well, so probably makes little sense to do a Repair. Performance in LO is equally poor, and in fact LO even crashes with it sometimes, whereas with Word I can still work with it, if sluggishly. Right now, only relieve comes from viewing the doc in Print as opp to Web layout. Incidentally, it is only in Print view that most of the doc's pictures are now visible - a problem that is likely not unrelated to the sluggishness problem we are discussing here.

Comment: Kingsoft and SoftMaker linked above also have a good reputation. This is probably a Word bug, and may have something to do with the choices you made during the installation of Office. I normally turn on some options that are defined as "installed on first use", mostly having to do with dictionaries/spellchecking. I wish you good luck, but I am now fresh out of ideas.

Comment: I think you have officially helped out as much and beyond what anyone would reasonably expect from a forum like this, and I thank you very much for it! :)

Comment: for the record: Softmaker handles the doc well, with no sluggishness - however does not provide the useful heading-based navigation side-pane that Word has, which is essential in order to find one's way around such a large doc. Trying Kingsoft now..

Comment: Kingsoft is also smooth in editing the doc, but cannot really function as a Word replacement for me, since it (the free version at least) lacks essential features such as defining macros, right-click menus to edit and drag&drop headings in Document Map, Zotero integration, multiple undo/redo lists and customised keyboard shortcuts (that can override built-in ones).

Comment: I see you are a very advanced user of Word. I think that if you can't find out why Word is slow only for this document and only on your computer(s), you could use a mix between Word and another editor, depending on the kind of editing.

Comment: yes i guess that's what i'll do for now. Thanks again, you've been amazing in this thread! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `.docx` with Libre Office writer
2. Click on `File`/`Save as` and in the drop down `Save as type` choose the .docx format.
3. In the alert, choose `Use Office Open XML Text Format` (do not choose ODF Format).
4. Open the `.docx` in MS Word.
5. If necessary, reapply your template: `File/Options/Add-Ins` in the drop-down `Manage` (bottom), select `Templates` and `Go`. Then choose your templates, check `Automatically update document styles` and click `Ok`
6. If necessary, reapply the style to the footnote references : in the style ribbon, right click on `Footnote Reference` and click on `Select All`, wait for MS Word to select all your footnote references and then click on the Footnoote Reference style (this reapply the style to all the footnore references).
7. If necessary, do step 6 but with `Endnote Reference`

This works because Libre Office Writer cleans the code of the .docx